# Como para o desactivar el efecto slideToggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero que cuando el usuario presione el boton de editar, el efecto del slideToggle() se detenga, el boton editar permite que el contenido de una etiqueta sea editable, pero el problema es cuando el usuario hace click o doble click a la etiqueta editable, ya que asi se muestra el efecto del slideToggle() y puede incomodar un poco al usuario.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.titulo_hijo').on('click',function(){
        let titulo_hijo = $(this).next();
        titulo_hijo.slideToggle();
    });

    $('.eliminar').on('click', function(){
        let eliminar = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
        eliminar.remove();
    });

    $('.editar').on('click', function(){
        let editar = $(this).parent().prev();
        editar.attr("contentEditable","true");
        editar.focus();
    });

});
```

```css
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contenedor_item{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.titulo_hijo{
    width: 95%;
    height: 50px;
}

.titulo_hijo{
    background: tomato;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.hijo{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 95%;
    display: none;
}

.titulo_hijo, .nieto{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #757575;
}

.nieto{
    background: wheat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.iconos{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.eliminar{
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Pregunta</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index5.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index5.css">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div class="contenedor_item">
            <div class="titulo_hijo"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
            <div class="hijo">
                <div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
                <div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
                <div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="contenedor_item">
            <div class="titulo_hijo"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
            <div class="hijo">
                <div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
                <div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
                <div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="contenedor_item">
            <div class="titulo_hijo"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
            <div class="hijo">
                <div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
                <div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
                <div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes lograr lo que quieres con `event.stopPropagation()` asi:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.titulo_hijo').on('click',function(){
        let titulo_hijo = $(this).next();
        titulo_hijo.slideToggle();
    });

    $('.eliminar').on('click', function(){
        let eliminar = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
        eliminar.remove();
    });

    $('.editar').on('click', function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        let editar = $(this).parent().prev();
        editar.attr("contentEditable","true");
        editar.focus();
    });

});
```

```css
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contenedor_item{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.titulo_hijo{
    width: 95%;
    height: 50px;
}

.titulo_hijo{
    background: tomato;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.hijo{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 95%;
    display: none;
}

.titulo_hijo, .nieto{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #757575;
}

.nieto{
    background: wheat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.iconos{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.eliminar{
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Pregunta</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index5.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index5.css">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div class="contenedor_item">
            <div class="titulo_hijo"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
            <div class="hijo">
                <div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
                <div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
                <div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="contenedor_item">
            <div class="titulo_hijo"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
            <div class="hijo">
                <div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
                <div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
                <div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="contenedor_item">
            <div class="titulo_hijo"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
            <div class="hijo">
                <div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
                <div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
                <div class="nieto"><p>Titulo editable</p><div class="iconos"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/20/000000/pencil.png" class="editar" alt="Editar" title="Editar"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/20/000000/waste-filled.png" class="eliminar" alt="Eliminar" title="Eliminar"></div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```